# Multiples validation into ng-disabled dont work

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to validate all fields of a form with angularjs 1.5, validation requires, full fields, and enable buttons in case these fields are full, I have already checked several operators but this does not work well, `ng-disabled = "! ( var1 && var2 && var3 && var4) "`. I need your help please leave reference code.

Thank you very much

AngularJS: **1.5.11**

[Code Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/l6f6fKuLnqOXuHHYpga0)

Comment: Could you specify the problem in a more detailed way ?

Comment: it is ng-disabled ....... not ng-disable

Comment: **I want to validate multiple fields required in the form with ng-disabled**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a form, you won't need to check for individual fields, just check for form validity:

```
<form role="form" name="testForm" novalidate>
    <input type="text" name="field1" ng-model="obj.field1" required>

    <input type="text" name="field2" ng-model="obj.field2" required>

    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="testForm.$invalid">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @Yaser , but what happens if any field is not filled as I notify the user.

Comment: You can find all of them in form

Comment: Thank you very much @Yaser, thanks to your advice I have solved my problem, without your help I would not have done it immediately, thank you very much :D